# variable definition gives an error in a for..in loop

Tags: bash, shell

How to define a variable in a for..in loop

**Example:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
api ="api keys"
for i in {1..305}; do
  wget "https://api.shodan.io/shodan/host/search?key=$api&query=&facets={facets}&page=$i"
done
```

But this gives an error of:

```
./script.sh: line 2: api: command not found
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: thanks found solution

Comment: This has nothing to do with the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash variable declarations are **space sensitive**. So don't surround variable declarations with white space. Have a look at [rule SC1068](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1068).

```sh
# Change:
api ="api keys" 
# To:
api="api keys"
```

Comment: this worked 
a `space` made my day